# Sign in button should disapear when user signed in and logout button appear using devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

friends i just want that when a user signed in then a button of "Login Here" should disapear and logout button should appear.When a user logout then "Login Here" button again should appear on header and logout should disappear. I am using devise on rails 4. Kindly suggest me how i should do that.What is the best and easy way to do that. I will be highly thank ful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This for login button

```
<%= link_to "Login Here", new_user_session_path unless user_signed_in? %>
```

This for logout

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete if user_signed_in? %>
```

`user_signed_in?` is devise's method which returns true or false

Comment: Thank u so much RSB :) This exact what i want.